# how to find out if running inside KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Is there a way to find out if OS(linux) is running inside KVM guest..

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/easy-way-to-determine-virtualization-technology

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Grep `dmesg`, there should be at least one line containing `kvm`. On my machines:

```
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:5dd801, boot clock
[    0.000000] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:1023801, primary cpu clock
```

Alternativly check `/proc/cpuinfo`, it contains a line:

```
model name : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.9.1
```

But, the problem is: You can't be sure you are an KVM guest (on top of QEMU) or only a QEMU-Guest.

Comment: kvm-clock clocksource might be not present or disabled for stability reasons.

Comment: You may want to add `dmidecode` to the list of ways that might show if you are running virtualized, it works well with VMWare.

Comment: The first worked for me but the second shows the regular intel model name

Answer (score 11):

You can check if [imvirt](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html) or [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) which are available for several Linux distros, including Ubuntu, can help you.

Comment: In my experience `imvirt` is more accurate.

Answer (score 9):

```
systemd-detect-virt
```

returns on [this Ubuntu 18.04 KVM setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-16-04-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792):

```
kvm
```

and on my host:

```
none
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/easy-way-to-determine-virtualization-technology

Tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

Answer (score 7):

Current versions of `lscpu` also show if a hypervisor is detected:

```
# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Model name:            Intel Core 2 Duo P9xxx (Penryn Class Core 2)
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2659.936
BogoMIPS:              5319.87
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is `dmidecode -s 'system-product-name'`

```
[samveen@vm1 ~]$ sudo dmidecode -s 'system-product-name'
KVM
```

Comment: Did not work with this Ubuntu 18.04 on Ubuntu 18.04 setup: https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1046792/15 , it just output: `Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX , 1996)`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Please check the other DMI information fields as well. I dont have access to an Ubuntu based KVM host to test. In most cases, the`system-product-name` identifier gives the expected answer, even in cases like `VirtualBox` and `VMWare`.